# Actionbar icon not showing despite showAsAction="always"

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I'm trying to implement a menu in a ListActivity.  Here's how I'm declaring the menu item:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:title="@string/camera_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/cam"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

And this is what the preview shows in Android Studio:

[image]

The preview suggests everything is fine. It shows the camera icon that I put in the res/drawable folder.
Yet, when I try to run it in an emulator (Nexus 4 API 22), this is how the app shows up:

[image]

So the actual emulator is pushing the icon into the overflow menu despite being set as showAsAction="always".

This is how I am inflating the menu in the ListActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possibly because you have used `app:showAsAction`. So if you are using support library, simply add `android:showAsAction` beside `app:showAsAction`. This have to solve your problem.